# Does PHP parse multiple functions simultaneously?

Tags: php, multithreading, parsing

I'm curious to know exactly how PHP would parse a number of functions with your standard configuration that you would find on most servers. Does PHP complete one function before moving on to the next, or can it fire off and loop through multiple functions at one time?

**For example:**

```
function1();
function2();
function3();
```

Considering the example above, would php generally complete function1 before executing function2?

Comment: It will execute in a sequence. first 1,2,nd 3rd. you can loop through the function.

Comment: Imagine if `function1`, `function2`, and `function3` work on the same underlying data for a moment and you'll understand why the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paul Crovella points out, The entire script is compiled, then executed in the order it is written. More interesting to me, is the order of nested functions, like:

```
echo ucfirst(strtolower("bOB")); //Bob
```

`strtolower()` runs first, then `ucfirst()`.

Comment: Why is that order of nested functions interesting to you? How could `ucfirst` ever possibly run on a not-yet-computed value?